# Change table cell positions by strings using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to change table cell positions using jQuery.

## Before

```
— kiwi fruit
— Peach
— banana
green | fruit:  kiwi fruit
pink | fruit:  Peach
yellow | fruit:  banana
Sour | fruit:  kiwi fruit
sweet | fruit:  Peach
sweet | fruit:  banana
```

## After - I want it change this way.

```
— kiwi fruit
green | fruit:  kiwi fruit
Sour | fruit:  kiwi fruit
— Peach
pink | fruit:  Peach
sweet | fruit:  Peach
— banana
yellow | fruit:  banana
sweet | fruit:  banana
```

## They use the same format below.

```
"- [fruit]"
" | fruit:  [fruit]"
```

*2nd one before the [fruit], two spaces

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>— kiwi fruit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>— Peach</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>— banana</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>green | fruit:  kiwi fruit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pink | fruit:  Peach</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>yellow | fruit:  banana</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sour | fruit:  kiwi fruit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sweet | fruit:  Peach</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sweet | fruit:  banana</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I made it with sources below, but it's not practical because other fruit like 'apple','cherry',etc. can be added in the future and each time I add the new fruit I have to edit my sources.

```
$("tr:contains(' | fruit:  kiwi fruit')").insertAfter("tr:contains('— kiwi fruit')");
$("tr:contains(' | fruit:  Peach')").insertAfter("tr:contains('— Peach')");
$("tr:contains(' | fruit:  banana')").insertAfter("tr:contains('— banana')");
```

Thank you!

I asked this question 2 days ago and have not found any solution.
If someone could help me with this quiestion, I would really appriciate it.

Comment: You need to parse the text to extract the fruit, then construct the matching header cell.  Can you confirm that all of them use the same format " | fruit:  [fruit]" and "- [fruit]"?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
I just edited my question and added about format.